# jQuery: if else .click not working

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

I've got to be missing something really simple here. All I want to do is make the color of all list items with a class of "link" toggle between blue and black. I've read through half a dozen posts and haven't figured out an answer yet.

**jfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y8K2x/1/

**HTML:**

```
<button>Toggle Link Color</button>
<ul>
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="link">Link 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="link">Link 4</li>
    <li class="link">Link 5</li>
    <li class="item">Item 6</li>
    <li class="link">Link 7</li>
    <li class="item">Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

**Here's the JS:**

```
$('button').click(function () {
var linkColor = $('.link').css('color');
if (linkColor == '#0099ff') {
    $('.link').css('color', '#000000');
} else if (linkColor == '#000000') {
    $('.link').css('color', '#0099ff');
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier (or cleaner) to just use:

**jQuery**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.link').toggleClass('link, link1');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.link {
    color: #000000;
}
.link1 {
    color: #0099ff;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/S95cv/)**

(BTW, jQuery returns RGB values for color, not hex)

Comment: +1, and from jquery website " Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)."

Answer (score 1):

A simple `console.log` of `linkColor` will show that the color is in rgb format, not hex.

```
$('button').click(function () {

var linkColor = $('.link').css('color');

if (linkColor == 'rgb(0, 153, 255)') {

    $('.link').css('color', '#000000');

} else if (linkColor == 'rgb(0, 0, 0') {

    $('.link').css('color', '#0099ff');

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try code maybe can help

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var that = $(this);

    if(that.hasClass('blue')) {        
         $('.link').css('color', '#000000');
         $('button').removeClass('blue');       
    } else {
        $('.link').css('color', '#0099ff');
       that.addClass('blue');

    }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/3qSkr/1/